# IIS7 affects the encoding?

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, character-encoding

I have a website on live server, and I have a the same website on local machine.  both using the same database. Some links are in Arabic.

The links are ok on live server, but it is corruptted on local machine.

Both Live server and local machione are hosting the website using IIS 7.

I think that the only chance is related to IIS configuration but how??

Thanks

Comment: All links corrupted or just the Arabic / non-ASCII ones? Are you generating the links on your pages yourself or are you using ASP.NET's helper functions? How are you encoding the URLs if you generate them yourself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the globalization tag in web.config and see if the values are matching on your local and live environments.